# spcolor color palette tool header color is not applying

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have created a spcolor file  and included it in a template page background and link colors are working fine but the header color alone not applying

Comment: You need to verify whether the new CSS is being applied or not in developer tools. Provide some more details in your question would be better to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you are editing the correct colorpalette color. 
You can do this by searching the `COREV15.css` (located in the sharepoint hive for example `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1031\STYLES\COREV15.css`, or under `https://yourSharePoint/_layouts/15/1031/styles/corev15.css`);

For example

```
<s:color name="BodyText" value="444444" />
```

Can be found in the `COREV15.CSS` as replace tag

```
.sp-peoplepicker-topLevel,
.sp-peoplepicker-topLevelDisabled,
.sp-peoplepicker-autoFillContainer,
.ms-inputBox
{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Lines")] */ border:1px solid #ababab;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"BackgroundOverlay",opacity:"1")] */ background-color:#fff;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"BackgroundOverlay")] */ background-color:rgba( 255,255,255,0.85 );
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"BodyText")] */ color:#444;
}
```

So to check where the color if your desired element comes from, you simply use the browser devlopment tools to get the css rule that applies the color. Search for the color in the `COREV15.css`and hope there is an `[ReplaceColor(themeColor:"TheColorYouNeedToModify")]` tag there.